# How can you quantify the effect of a campaign in CausalImpact?

Tags: r, causalimpact

I have been working with the CausalImpact R-package to check whether new campaigns or features had a significant impact on a time-series. 
I would like to know if it is possible to quantify this impact (i.e. how many more units were sold due to this change) if the result had been a significant one.

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what is reported as 'Absolute effect' in the summary of a CausalImpact object, say, `impact`:

`summary(impact)`

(See the examples in the package documentation, `example("CausalImpact")`.)